# Send copy of contact us form with checkbox

Tags: magento-1.7, forms, send-mail

I am using Magento's contact us form, which, at the moment, doesn't send a copy of the contact us form to the customer who is filling the form in.

I want to control this with a checkbox, therefore i have added a checkbox to the `form.phtml` page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sendcopy" value="Yes" checked/>
```

How can i configure the send e-mail function so that it sends out a copy (to the e-mail address which is filled in, in the e-mail field of the contact form) of the e-mail when the checkbox is checked, and doesn't send a copy when it is not checked?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using bcc function `addBcc($post['email])` after -`setReplyTo($post['email'])`  at class `Mage_Contacts_IndexController`  of function postAction().

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
/* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
    <!-- add this -->
    ->addBcc($post['email'])
    ->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
    null,
    array('data' => $postObject)
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand this part will send the e-mail as BCC to the sender. How can i build in the check, that this function will only be active when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: yes. this can do this bcc

Comment: I have added the line, but no e-mail is being sent unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this. What's to stop a bot filling out spam content, someone else's email, ticking the box and turning your magento store into a spam server.

If you do decide to do this make sure you have captcha on the form.